# Is the rhombic dodecahedron the only isohedral polyhedron that tiles 3-space (other than the cube)?

Tags: geometry, 3d, polyhedra, tiling, tessellations

**Is the [rhombic dodecahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombic_dodecahedral_honeycomb)**

[image]

**the only face-transitive (or *isohedral*, i.e. all faces are the same) polyhedron that seamlessly tiles 3-dimensional Euclidean space (other than the cube)?**

I'm looking for an answer to this question and although Wikipedia provides a lot of lists for 3-tesselations I cannot find a definite closure. In particular, if the above statement were true I'd expect it to be listed on the tesselation's Wiki page, but no such statement exists, which leaves some doubt in me whether it is actually the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does the (irregular) space-filling octahedron meet your criteria? (The tiles are not all obtained from a single tile by translation, i.e., this is not a lattice tiling. Instead, there are three families of mutually-orthogonal tiles in a tessellation.)

[image: Space-filling octahedron]

Comment: Looks promising. What is the symmetry group? Looks like six of these octahedra meet at every vertex of the tiling, so this is clearly not just the cubic tiling in disguise.

Comment: Assuming unit cubes, I believe the group is generated by unit translations in the coordinate directions and quarter-turns about "long" edges (those that bisect faces of cubes). Certainly the symmetry group is non-Abelian, since it contains $S_{3}$.

Comment: The symmetry group for the octahedron is isomorphic to the cube.

Comment: I actually meant the space group of the corresponding tesselation.

Comment: @user86418: I believe you are right and your group base seems correct as well, which clearly makes this tesselation different from both the cubic and the rhombic dodecahedral honeycombs (whose symmetry groups are generated by translations alone). I therefore accept this answer.

Comment: Each octahedron is $D_{4h}$, but the use of three orientations in the tiling adds a threefold axis and makes the symmrtry of the tiling $O_h$.

Answer (score 4):

No. The body-centered cubic tetrahedron tiles it as well. [image: bcc tetrahedron]

Please note that an isohedral polyhedron is not just a polyhedron in which all faces are congruent, but one in which all the faces also lie in the same symmetry orbit (which unfortunately is not the case for the irregular space-filling octahedron).

Comment: "not the case for the irregular space-filling octahedron". Why not? This octahedron is $D_{4h}$-symmetric, which should contain all the point groups necessary to identify thes faces.

Answer (score 2):

The rhombic dodecahedron could be split-up into six isohedral octahedrons mentioned above.
But each octahedron could be split-up further into four isohedral tetrahedrons (so the rhombic dodecahedron consists of 24 isohedral tetrahedrons).

Below is the view of this isohedral tetrahedron inside the half of the cube:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The rhombohedron works, though you may consider it too closely related to the cube to be of any interest:
[image]

Comment: The rhombohedron generates the same symmetry group as the cube and is therefore "the same tiling" in the sense of tesselation theory (just like a cuboid, which also tiles 3-space in the same way as the cube). This is therefore, unfortunately, not the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Truncated octahedron also tesselates 3-dimensional space.

Comment: This answer seems rather unclear to me.

Comment: Take the lattice of points $(i,j,k)$, $(i+1/2,j+1/2,k+1/2)$ with integer $i, j, k$. The lattice points' Voronoi polyhedra are truncated octahedra. Granted, not all the faces of each tile are congruent. However, the tiling's tiles are congruent and the tiling is isohedral. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_octahedron#Tessellations https://www.quinapalus.com/splatts.html

Comment: +1 yes; more details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/bitruncated_cubic_honeycomb

Answer (score 0):

The rhombohedron provided by Kaj Hansen does provide additional translational symmetries beyond those of a cubic tesselation — if the polyhedron is shaped properly.

Below is a reproduction of Kaj Hansen's picture, with additional lines indicating three pairs of parallel face diagonals.

[image]

In a rhomohedron the diagonals shown are congruent to each other. But if we shape the polyhedron so that these diaginals are *also* cobgruent to the edges, then the translations along these diaginals become symmetrically equivalent to those along the edges of the rhombohedron and the lattice becomes **face-centered cubic** or **cubic close-packed.**

The condition for this extra congruency is as follows: Body diagonal AB in the above figure measures $\sqrt6$ times the edges of the rhombohedron. Then the other body diagonals measure $\sqrt2$ times the edges and are also perpendicular to each other, making the six vertices besides A and B those of a regular octahedron. This regular octahedron corresponds the the face centers of the cubic unit cells with center of the octahedron corresponding to the empty body center of the cube. AB itself is a body diagonal of tge face-centered cube.